# Vertical Scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with Jquery when performing an operation. I can not get a full-page scroll effect from session one to session two and inverse, it works only from top to bottom, but from bottom to top it does not work.

```js
$(function() {
  var one = $(".one").offset().top;
  var two = $(".two").offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.one').scrollTop() + 1) {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: two
      }, 2000);
    } else if ($('.two').scrollTop() - 1) {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: one
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <section class="one"></section>
  <section class="two"></section>
```

Comment: Where are `uno` and `dos` in your HTML? I assume these should be references to the `one` and `two` elements?

Comment: yes, it's one and two are one and two

Comment: If you remove the +1 and -1 after the scrollTop() , it works i think? try it and if that this is not the desired effect, do comment.

Comment: Think you need to rethink this, if you're in area 2, as soon as you try and scroll up you're in area 1 so it scrolls to area 2... What is the behaviour that you actually want?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: "0"
}, 'slow');
   }
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <section class="one"></section>
  <section class="two"></section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Hello, if you run it in full screen, your code goes directly back up without pressing the arrow or without pressing you. And you can not go down again. But thank you very much